# (Windows) Base Address of a some program never changes

Tags: windows, base-address

I have aslr enabled and when I play some game called assault cube the base address of this program is always the same (00400000) I get it by doing GetModuleHandle(NULL) also tried to get it with windbg and it also says 00400000 and I was wondering how come it never changes since for the other programs it always changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you have [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) enabled globally, Windows only applies it to applications that specifically indicate that they support it. Doing otherwise could easily make legacy applications crash unexpectedly, leading to compatibility problems. All executables and supporting DLLs must explicitly indicate that they support ASLR.

Indicating that you support ASLR is something you do when linking the object file by specifying [the `/DYNAMICBASE` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384887.aspx) (at least if you're using Microsoft's linker). Modern versions of the linker have it turned on by default, but if your game was compiled with an older version of the toolset before dynamic address relocation support was the default (*e.g.*, VS 2008 and earlier) or with a linker from a different vendor, it is likely that it was not linked with ASLR support.

This is called out in [the relevant MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430720.aspx#aslr) (emphasis added):

> ASLR moves executable images into random locations when a system boots, making it harder for exploit code to operate predictably. **For a component to support ASLR, all components that it loads must also support ASLR.** For example, if A.exe consumes B.dll and C.dll, all three must support ASLR. **By default, Windows Vista and later will randomize system DLLs and EXEs, but DLLs and EXEs created by ISVs must opt in to support ASLR using the `/DYNAMICBASE` linker option.**

See also: [Vista ASLR is not on by default for image base addresses](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=100)

---

Note that you can *modify* the PE header of an existing binary, forcing it to support ASLR, by running the `editbin` utility available with the SDK. As with the linker, [the `/dynamicbase` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff820372.aspx) will turn it on.

Or, you can force ASLR globally by editing the following registry entry:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\MoveImages
```

Of course, neither of these actually change the code, so if there are compatibility problems, the application will break.